# Selenium chromewebdriver, headless + using profile. gives UI error

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to run chrome webdriver with a profile, so i can store cookies and username / passwords. However, when i try to combine this with headless mode, it errors:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63585/devtools/browser/ab7a020f-e412-4204-a53a-285e0b3a15c4
[0824/105430.911:ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(288)] Error writing DevTools active port to file
[0824/105430.916:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(19)] Unable to move the cache: 3
[0824/105430.916:ERROR:cache_util.cc(135)] Unable to move cache folder cookies/PresFox1\Default\GPUCache to cookies/PresFox1\Default\old_GPUCache_000
[0824/105430.917:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(169)] Unable to create cache
[0824/105430.917:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(600)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
```

Code:

```
public static void login(string username, string password)
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            //options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");

            options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=cookies/"+username);
            options.AddArgument("--headless");

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: Since it has problems with creating/moving folders/files: Are you sure that the application has the proper file system permissions where it's running?

Comment: yes, it works fine when i comment out the headless argument.

Comment: Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-d

Comment: Added the no sandbox and dev flags, but still same issue :(

Comment: Update, when running as administrator i only get the error: Lost UI shared context, but it still doesnt work

Comment: I have similar issues and suspect old instances of chrome are being resused, try killing all chrome processes

Comment: Any updates on this? did you figure what was the problem? Could you post a response to your question if you did?